# Get dictionary value from multiple dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of many dictionaries with only one key value pair like below.

```
List1 = [{'dept': 'a'}, {'country': 'India'}, {'name':'xyz'}, {'age':32}]
```

I want to extract `name` from this list by not using index number but with the dict key.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
List1 = [{'dept': 'a'}, {'country': 'India'}, {'name': 'xyz'}, {'age': 32}]

for dic in List1:
    name = dic.get('name')
    if name is not None:    # {'name': ''} which is acceptable.
        break
        
print(name)
```

output :

```
xyz
```

Answer (score 3):

Or use list comprehesion. It always looks better than a loop.

```
[dic['name'] for dic in List1 if 'name' in dic][0]
```

Comment: One possible downside to this is if `name` found in the first dictionary, this solution will iterate through all the items which is not needed.

Comment: @soroushbakhtiary While in theory you are right, practically the list is very short.